# Not able to render graphql data with react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am trying to display values from an API using apollo client, server, ReactJS and NodeJS, Below is the code to do this:

Client:

UserPosts.js:

```
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { USERPostedImages } from "./query";

function UserPosts() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USERPostedImages);
  
 
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.userPostedImages.map((data) => (
        <>
          <p key={data.posterName}>
            {data.url}----{data.description}
          </p>
          
        </>
      ))}
   
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserPosts;
```

query.js for the graphql queries:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const unsplashImages = gql`
  {
    unsplashImages {
      
      url
      posterName
      description

    }
  }
`;

export const USERPostedImages = gql`
  {
    userPostedImages {
      
      url
      posterName
      description

    }
  }
`;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import {NavLink, BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import UserPosts from './components/UserPosts';
import Bin from './components/Bin';
import Home from './components/Home';
import NewPost from './components/NewPost';
import UnsplashPosts from './components/UnsplashPosts';

import {
  ApolloClient,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider
} from '@apollo/client';
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000'
  })
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <header className='App-header'>
            <h1 className='App-title'>
              GraphQL Lab5
            </h1>
            <nav>
              <NavLink className='navlink' to='/'>
                Home
              </NavLink>
              <NavLink className='navlink' to='/my-bin'>
                Bin
              </NavLink>

              <NavLink className='navlink' to='/my-posts'>
                Posts
              </NavLink>

              <NavLink className='navlink' to='/new-post'>
                Create New Post
              </NavLink>
            </nav>
          </header>
          <Route exact path='/' component={UnsplashPosts} />
          <Route path='/my-bin/' component={Bin} />
          <Route path='/my-posts' component={UserPosts} />
          <Route path='/new-post' component={NewPost} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Server

index.js:

```
const {ApolloServer, gql} = require('apollo-server');
const axios = require('axios');
const uuid = require('uuid'); 
const bluebird = require('bluebird'); 
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient();

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);
   
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    photos: [Photo]
    post: [ImagePost]
    unsplashImages: [ImagePost]
    userPostedImages: [ImagePost]
  }
  
  type Photo {
    id: String
    username: String
  }

  type ImagePost {
    id: String!
    url: String!
    posterName: String!
    description: String
    userPosted: Boolean
    binned: Boolean
  }

  type Mutation {
    uploadImage(
      url: String!
      description: String
      posterName: String
    ): ImagePost
  }
 
`;


const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    unsplashImages: async (_, args) => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=2zceQd7D4SraKoqW_GjPzXboSup3TKRIPk7EXfJBcAs');
      const a =  data.map(imagePost => {
        return {
          id: imagePost.id,
          posterName: imagePost.user.name,
          url: imagePost.urls.raw,
          description: imagePost.description,
        }
      })
      return a;
    },
  userPostedImages: async (_,args) => {
    let history = await client.lrangeAsync("postedImagesList",0,100).map(JSON.parse);
    return history;
  }
},
    Mutation: {
      uploadImage: async (_,args) => {
        //const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=2zceQd7D4SraKoqW_GjPzXboSup3TKRIPk7EXfJBcAs');
        const newPost = {
          id: uuid.v4(),
          url: args.url,
          description: args.description,
          posterName: args.posterName,
          binned: false,
          userPosted: true,

        }
        await client.lpushAsync("postedImagesList",JSON.stringify(newPost));
      }
    }

};

const server = new ApolloServer({typeDefs, resolvers});

server.listen().then(({url}) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url} `);
});
```

When I run my client I get the below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userPostedImages')
    at UserPosts (UserPosts.js:22:1)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, my server is working fine and am able to see data in graphql playground but nothing shows up on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is not available (`null`) yet because it is still fetching, so to handle this, use conditional rendering with `loading` value.

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(USERPostedImages);

if(error) {
 return <h1> error</h1>;
}

if(loading) {
 return <h1> loading</h1>;
}

....
```